# SELENIUUM WEB DRIVER

Tags: python, selenium, automation

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync,types
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
import time
import asyncio


email="****@gmail.com"
Password="*****"
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://qxbroker.com/en/sign-in/")
username_textbox = driver.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys(email)
password_textbox= driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(Password)
login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tab-1"]/form/button/div').click()

api_id=123456
api_hash='DFDGGGGGGGDGBGFBGFBFGB'
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)
@client.on(events.NewMessage)
async def handler(event):
  if "EUR/USD" in event.raw_text:
    if "UP" in event.raw_text:
        print("UP")
        Up_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('// *[ @ id = "root"] / div / div[1] / main / div[2] / div[1] / div / div[6] / div[1] / button').click()
    elif 'DOWN' in event.raw_text:
        down_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[4]/button').click()
        print("DOWN")

client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

This is my code i want to select the time from that website but i don't know how if i am using click command it shows error of use await command.The time option was like dropdown menu. please help me. i want to set a trade for five to ten minutes duration. but this code just press what i set in that website.but i want that code select the time itslef automatically